# default value for ChoiceField in modelform

Tags: django, django-forms

I have  problem with django:
models.py:

```
SUSPEND_TIME = (
    ('0', '0'),
    ('10', '10'),
    ('15', '15'),
    ('20', '20'),


class Order(models.Model):  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)  
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)  
    ...
    processed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    suspend_time = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SUSPEND_TIME, default='0')  
    ..
```

form.py:

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('suspend_time', 'processed')
```

view.py:

```
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
        except Order.DoesNotExist:
            order = None
        else:
            form = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=order)
            if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            ....
```

then I send ajax request to update instance with only `"processed"` param..
`form.is_valid` is always `False` if I don't send `"suspend_time" !`
if request contain `{'suspend_time': 'some_value' ...}` `form.is_valid` is `True`
I don't understand why ? `suspend_time` has default value.. and order.`suspend_time` always has some `value: default` or other from choices.
why after `form = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=order)`  `form['suspend_time'].value()` is `None`, other fields `(city, processed)`  has normal value .

Comment: as I understand the summary of question is why `form = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=order)` form is invalid, while some values not in post, but present in instance(order). Am I correct?

Comment: @Mykola Kharechko If you'd like the author to make his code snippet more concise, leave a comment suggesting that, but please don't edit out portions of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is as expected. The form should validate with given data. i.e. Whatever required fields are defined in the form, should be present in the data dictionary to instantiate it.
It will not use data from instance to populate fields that are not provided in form data.

Text from [django model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

*If you’re building a database-driven app, chances are you’ll have forms that map closely to Django models. For instance, you might have a BlogComment model, and you want to create a form that lets people submit comments. In this case, it would be redundant to define the field types in your form, because you’ve already defined the fields in your model.*

*For this reason, Django provides a helper class that let you create a Form class from a Django model.*